# How to add manually contacts group to Android database?

Tags: database, android, emulation, contacts, android-sdk-2.1

I want to define some Contact Groups.

I am wondering where and how does Android store the groups. Maybe in a Sqlite database?
If so, will be able to run a insert on it?

Otherwise how do you add new Contacts Group via the emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can't do an insert directly.  You need to look into [ContentProviders](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), [Contacts.Groups](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/Contacts.Groups.html) and [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html).

Answer (score 0):

To add a contact group programmatically:

```
  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  cv.put(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE, groupName);
  cv.put(ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE, 1);
  getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, cv);
```